# Using user input to call functions

Tags: python

I was trying to make a "game" in Python where the user inputs a command. However, I do not know whether you can take that input to be a function name. This is my current effort:

```
def move():
    print("Test.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    input("Press enter to begin.")
    currentEnvironment = getNewEnvironment(environments)
    currentTimeOfDay = getTime(timeTicks, timeOfDay)
    print("You are standing in the {0}. It is {1}.".format(currentEnvironment, currentTimeOfDay))
    command = input("> ")
    command()
```

Here, the input was move, as I wanted to try and call that function (as a potential end user might). However, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Text Adventure.py", line 64, in <module>
    command()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I was wondering if there was any way that I could allow a user to 'move' in the game, which the program achieves by calling the "move" function.

Comment: If you could make this work, what happens when the user types `os.system('rm -rf')`?

Comment: @DanielRoseman -- Nothing because `rm` needs to be provided with something to remove.  However, `os.system('rm -rf ~')` could be bad ;)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not hugely familiar with the OS module.

Comment: Hi Jon, `command` becomes a `string` as soon as it gets input, and you cannot make a function call out of it. Hence, Python tells you `'str' object is not callable` What you could do is have a generic `user_command()` function that uses `switch-case` to get your program to do what you want it to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you're using python3.x where `input` returns a string.  To recover the python2.x behavior, you need `eval(input())`.  However, you shouldn't do this.  It's likely to lead to a bad day.

---

A better idea is to put the functions into a dictionary --

```
def move():
    #...

def jump():
    #...

function_dict = {'move':move, 'jump':jump }
```

and then:

```
func = input('>')  #raw_input on python2.x
function_dict[func]()
```

---

The following code works for me on python3.2.

```
def move():
    print("Test.")

func_dict = {'move':move}
if __name__ == "__main__":
    input("Press enter to begin.")
    currentEnvironment = "room" #getNewEnvironment(environments)
    currentTimeOfDay = "1 A.M." #getTime(timeTicks, timeOfDay)
    print("You are standing in the {0}. It is {1}.".format(currentEnvironment, currentTimeOfDay))
    command = input("> ")
    func_dict[command]()
```

Comment: Where do I put the dictionary, exactly? I'm getting: NameError: name 'move' is not defined

Comment: @Jon -- `function_dict` needs to be created after the functions are created.  e.g. `def move(): ...; def move_left(): ...; function_dict = {'move':move, ... }`

Comment: Edit - was a bug with something I accidentally left in there previously, thanks a bunch :)

Comment: @Jon -- I posted a working version of the snippet you had above using python 3.2

Comment: This dictionary approach is extremely pythonic.  Everything in python is a dictionary.  For example a module is just dictionary with functions as values and a string name.

Comment: How might you provide function specific params with this approach? or effectively store what a func returns?

Comment: @RickM. -- you can always "curry" your function arguments using a `lambda` (or, depending on your tastes -- `functools.partial`).  I'm not sure what you mean about storing what the function returns, but maybe `functools.lru_cache`?

Comment: @mgilson Hi Mate, Still helping 8 years later :-) , Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the `cmd` module. See [this](http://docs.python.org/library/cmd.html).

It is normally used for shell style comman dlanguages, but it can also be used to create simple text style adventure games.

You can create commands by creating a new method on the `Cmd` subclass.

E.g.

```
def do_move(self, args):
    if self.next_room.has_snake():
        print "The next room contains a poisonous snake. It bites you and you die."
    else:
        print "The room is empty"
```

Comment: I'm looking to use this in school, where cmd is not accessible.

Comment: Just to clarify, as I am not sure if I was clear on this. I do not mean `cmd` as in the windows command prompt. I mean the python `cmd` module, which should be available in any python installation.

Comment: Or do you mean that you are not allowed to use the `cmd` python module?

Answer (score 2):

You can access functions by name using:

```
function = globals()[function_name]
```

if the function is in the current module, or

```
function = getattr(other_module, function_name)
```

You should also take measures to disallow calling arbitrary functions, for example, prefixing:

```
 def cmd_move() # ok to call this
 def cmd_jump() # ok to call this

 def internal_func....

 cmd = raw_input('>') # e.g. "move"
 fun = globals()['cmd_' + cmd]
 fun()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's usually better to re-use code as Hans suggests, but if you wanted to input commands and run them manually, it would be MUCH safer to have a dictionary of valid commands than to directly execute user-provided input.

```
cmd = { 'move': move, 'jump': jump, 'look': look }
```